# Can I use png images inside a resource dll with ImageSearch function?

Tags: autohotkey

So, I want to develop a simple automation script for myself and distribute it to some friends and want it to look professional.

The script uses some png files (in the script root folder) to do [ImageSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm) function.

The thing is that I don't want to distribute it with png files (I know about [FileInstall](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileInstall.htm)) or to have the programs install the png files in the script directory. What I really want is a dll packed with the png images, so that the common user doesn't even know that the file contains images (or a similar solution) and be able to access them from the script.

My question then is: Is it possible to use ImageSearch and make it use images inside a dll packed with pictures? Any similar approach that I can use not to have png files along the script?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

From the [link you posted](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ImageSearch.htm), it appears that this is indeed possible to use `ImageSearch` with DLL files as it is explicitly mentioned.

> Other sources of icons include the following types of files: EXE, **DLL**, CPL, SCR, and other types that contain icon resources.

Note that you may need to scale the image(s) if these are not actually icons.

> . . . icons loaded from ICO, DLL, or EXE files are scaled to the system's default small-icon size, which is usually 16 by 16 (you can force the actual/internal size to be used by specifying *w0 *h0).

As for a similar approach, you could alternatively use one of the other file formats mentioned instead of DLL.